# What are the requirements for a Brazilian citizen working in Spain?

Tags: working-visas, spain, brazilian-citizens

A Brazilian friend is considering a move to Spain to live with a friend for a year.

What are the requirements for obtaining an Spanish work visa for a Brazilian citizen?

Comment: There is an agreement about short stays covering a lot of situations but there is no such thing as an “EU work visa” and I am pretty sure there are no reciprocal agreements about that. I suggest you focus your question on Spain (can't provide more info on that, unfortunately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Brazilian national can enter the Schengen Area, including Spain, visa free for up to 3 months during a 6 month period following the date of first entry. However, visa-free entrance does not confer the right to work, either in Spain or any Schengen country.

An individual can’t apply directly for a work permit. The employer in Spain has to do it, through the  Immigration Office (Oficina de Extranjeros) at the nearest [Subdelegación del Gobierno](https://www.policia.es/documentacion/oficinas/oficinas_extran.html) or [Unidad de Grandes Empresas](http://extranjeros.empleo.gob.es/es/UnidadGrandesEmpresas/)

After that has been accomplished, your friend would [apply for the work visa (by employment)](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/MANILA/en/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Applying-for-Visa/LongtermVisas/Pages/Work-(employment)-Visa.aspx) through the Spanish Consulate in his home country.